# How to change CSS values with live preview. Less.js?

Tags: less

I want to make a page in an Admin CP where you can customize the values of some CSS properties, e.g. background-colors. This should have a live preview like e.g. in Wordpress, but I don't know how.

I'm using LESS for the styles, so I thought about using Less.js and

less.modifyVars()

It works, but the problem is, it takes about one second to show the change in the page, since the less file is not small, because I also import Bootstrap.

Any other idea how to do something like this?

Comment: If you need speed, the only way to get it faster is to move all your customisable stuff into a separate CSS/styles and modify those independently of your base CSS (it does not really matter if you do this via `less.modifyVars` or via some scripting or whatever). With Bootstrap it can't go below 1 sec, as it's just the time it compiles in (which is no wonder considering it's ~70 files with 8K lines of code. One could of course write a super fast Less compiler utilizing C/C++/Fortran with SIMD and GPU power decreasing BS compile time down to ~20ms, but you won't be able to use it in a browser).